# NSDictionary to NSArray not converting (Signal SIGBRT)

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have a very simple HTTP query that runs and grabs some JSON object in another class. I have an NSDictionary object called finalDataArray being defined. I am basically trying to loop through and append names to a table, the number of rows are being calculated correctly. finalDataArray.count

But when I try to do this, I get an error on the first line below.

```
NSArray *contactArray = [finalDataArray allKeys];
NSLog(@"%@", contactArray);
```

Comment: What error? Gonna need a bit more than this.

Comment: Are you sure that *finalDataArray* is a dictionary? NSArray won't respond to the *allKeys* method.

Comment: These two lines are perfectly correct, there might be some other source of error, if you can post full code. Or try breakpoint and step....to find the actual error in which statement. Just for naming convention never give name finalDataArray for NSDictionary object, it is not error, but must follow naming convention!!!

Comment: in my ViewController.h 

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    
    NSDictionary *contactObject;
    
}

In my other class "contactTableView.m"

I am importing the ViewController.h... How would one access this property? Everything I try comes back as NULL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I am such a newb, I didn't realize that if you had a "Miltidimensional" JSON object... it should be NSDictionary, but if you have a single dimenstional object... it should be NSArray which fixes my issue...

Thanks for all the help.